# Can't get AWS AMPLIFY to build

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, deployment, lint, tsconfig

I have a project that builds fine locally, but AWS amplify gives me this error.

```
2022-12-01T22:50:27.747Z [WARNING]: Failed to compile.
2022-12-01T22:50:27.749Z [WARNING]: ./src/aws-exports.js
Error: Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/src/aws- 
exports.js` using `parserOptions.project`: <tsconfigRootDir>/tsconfig.json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your 
parserOptions.project
See the TypeScript ESLint docs for more info: https://typescript- 
eslint.io/docs/linting/troubleshooting##i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured- 
to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file
info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
2022-12-01T22:50:27.760Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
```

My tsconfig.json

```
"include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.cjs", 
"**/*.mjs", "/src/aws-exports.js"],
"exclude": ["node_modules", "amplify", ]
}
```

Any idea what I am missing?